# editing List content in Python

Tags: python, string, list, edit

I have a variable `data`:

```
data = [b'script', b'-compiler', b'123cds', b'-algo', b'timing']
```

I need to convert it to remove all occurrence of "b" in the list.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure whether it would help - but it works with your sample:

```
initList = [b'script', b'-compiler', b'123cds', b'-algo', b'timing']
resultList = [str(x) for x in initList ]
```

Or in P3:

```
resultList = [x.decode("utf-8") for x in initList ] # where utf-8 is encoding used
```

Check more on [decode function.](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#str.decode)

Also you may want to take a look into [the following related SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-byte-array-to-python-string)

Comment: Hey Artsiom, I doesn't work on my end. For your reference, I am running python 3.2.2 on windows.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = [b'script', b'-compiler', b'123cds', b'-algo', b'timing']
>>> map(str, a)
['script', '-compiler', '123cds', '-algo', 'timing']
```

Comment: I am getting following result instead of the formatted list:
<map object at 0x00FBF890>

Comment: Yes, in Python 3 `map` is lazy. If you want to force it to a list use `list(map(str, a))`, but for many purposes you can just use the output from `map` directly and it will convert the individual elements as they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
strin = "[b'script', b'-compiler', b'123cds', b'-algo', b'timing']"
arr = strin.strip('[]').split(', ')
res = [part.strip("b'") for part in arr]

>>> res
['script', '-compiler', '123cds', '-algo', 'timing']
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I am getting the following error
"
arr = data1.strip('[]').split(', ')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: This example works with `strin = "[b'script', b'-compiler', b'123cds', b'-algo', b'timing']"`, which is a string, not a list.